# Form validation: how to get the actual length of a field shown in errors?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

My form in Flask WTF looks like this:

```
class PublishForm(Form):
    tweet = TextAreaField('tweet', [validators.DataRequired(), validators.Length(123, 123)])
```

When I show the error in template, I don't get the actual length shown. Any idea how to achieve this?

```
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        {% for field in form.errors %}
                            {% for error in form.errors[field] %}
                                {{ error }}
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up fixing it like this:

```
                    {% if form.errors %}
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            {% set count = form.tweet.data|length %}
                            {% for field in form.errors %}
                                {% for error in form.errors[field] %}
                                    {{ error }}
                                    Actual Length: {{ count }}
                                {% endfor %}
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% endif %}
```